# wrong R version installed during dockerization

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a problem with dockerization of shiny apps. I have a small shiny app which was developed in R 3.4.4 . I want to dockerize it. I have written my dockerfile like this :

```
FROM r-base:3.4.4  
MAINTAINER aurelien beliard (email@domain.com)
RUN apt update 

RUN apt install -y libcairo2-dev\
   liblapack-dev \
   liblapack3 \
   libopenblas-base \
   libopenblas-dev \
   libxml2-dev \
   libssl1.0.2 \
   libssl-dev \
   libcurl4-openssl-dev \
   libudunits2-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny',dependencies=TRUE,  repos='cran.rstudio.com/')";
RUN apt install -y  gdebi-core

RUN wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb
RUN gdebi -n shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb
RUN apt update
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2',dependencies=TRUE, repos='cran.rstudio.com/')";
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinydashboard',dependencies=TRUE, repos='cran.rstudio.com/')";
RUN R -e "source('https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R');\
   biocLite('Gviz')";

COPY ./sources/ /srv/shiny-server/wes-cnv
COPY ./data /srv/shiny-server/wes-cnv/data

EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

I use docker build and the R package seem to be installed with R3.5.1 and when i run the container in interactive mode and execute R in bash shell the R version is 3.5.1 :

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

and when i call ggplot2:

```
library('ggplot2')
```

I have this error :

```
Error in library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

ggplot2 seem to bug during the installation saying that library are installed in another R version :

```
Error : package ‘stringi’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
```

but shiny server work perfectly.

If someone have an explanation or/and a solution it will be very appreciated

ps : please be kind it my first question here and English is not my native language.

Comment: What makes you think that version 3.5.1 is installed? Please add that info to your question. `ggplot2 seem to bug ` what does that mean? Do you have any error messages? If so, please add them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FROM r-base:3.4.4` correctly installs R version 3.4.4, but your `apt install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev` then updates it to the latest version (which is 3.5.1).

You can test this interactively. Start with a very simple one-line `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM r-base:3.4.4
```

Build it as `docker build -t tester .` and run it interactively as `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash tester`:

```
root@0f5bb0fb300e:/# R --version | grep "R version"
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
```

So far so good! Let's run the next couple of lines of your Dockerfile:

```
root@0f5bb0fb300e:/# apt update
Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease [150 kB]
...
root@0f5bb0fb300e:/# apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  r-base-core r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-codetools r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial
...
```

Because your Dockerfile runs this last command with the `-y` flag, `docker build` automatically consents to upgrading R to the latest version.